# Context When Loading JS File Dynamically

Tags: javascript

I have a function that loads a JS file when I need it:

```
function loadjsFile(filename){
  var fileref=document.createElement('script');
  fileref.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
  fileref.setAttribute("src", filename);
  if (typeof fileref!="undefined"){
    document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(fileref);
  }
}
```

Test.js contains

```
var xxx = 123;
```

if I try to load this file I cannot see xxx (Uncaught ReferenceError: xxx is not defined)

```
loadjsFile("test.js");
$(document).ready(function(){
  console.log(xxx);
});
```

however if I run this in the debug console it works. Am I going about this the wrong way?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29938405/problems-with-dynamic-loading-in-javascript#answer-29939476

Comment: Thanks, makes perfect sense.